# How do you serve CXML files on a windows server 2003 r2 box?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

I have a file for http://www.getpivot.com/ that is a CXML file. It has been saved as a CXML on our windows 2003 server r2. It doesn't display, and just says

The request is not supported.

If I change the extension to XML, the file works. Is IIS blocking the filetype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the MIME-type

```
File name extension: .cxml
MIME type: text/xml
```

I tried the HelloWorld.cxml example from [Developer Info : Collection XML Schema](http://www.getpivot.com/developer-info/xml-schema.aspx) on my Win 7 machine and it did failed with the error

```
ModuleName="StaticFileModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="404", HttpReason="Not Found", HttpSubStatus="3", ErrorCode="The request is not supported.  (0x80070032)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

I added a mime-type as mentioned in the above article and the .cxml file does works.

```
File name extension: .cxml
MIME type: text/xml
```

Comment: I think your link is corrupted.

So the solution is... IIS6 > right mouse on website > HTTP Headers > Mime Types > New >  @Extension = CXML @MimeType = text/xml.

Comment: Yes, you will need the MIME type. I also corrected the link.